# Computing the Ind-completion of the terminal category

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be any category. $\text{Ind}(C)$ is the free completion under all filtered colimits.

Can you help me in computing the Ind-completion of the terminal category?

Comment: That is not the correct definition of Ind(C).  Filtered-colimit preserving functors from Ind(C) to an inductive category correspond to _arbitrary_ functors from C to an inductive category, not filtered-colimit preserving functors.

Comment: Sorry, I edited. I copy and pasted from somewhere in which was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ind-completion may be constructed as the closure of the representables in $\widehat{C}$ under filtered colimits. But the subcategory of representables in $\widehat{*}$ is a terminal category, so every functor into it is constant. Any filtered category $J$ is connected, so the colimit of a constant $J$-indexed functor at the representable $y*$ is just $y*$ itself. That is, the terminal category is its own Ind-completion.

To confirm, we can check the universal property. Given any functor $F:*\to D$, where $D$ has filtered colimits, the claim is that there exists a unique functor $*\to D$ extending $F$ and preserving filtered colimits; in other words the claim is simply that $F$ automatically preserves filtered colimits. But this follows by the same argument as above: namely, that the filtered colimit of a constant diagram on some object $x$ is simply $x$.

Comment: On the other hand the free completion under colimits is Set, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.